# How to correct unstable wifi connection through router?

Tags: networking, drivers, internet

I'm using an Asus Vivobook laptop which originally comes with Win10. I installed Ubuntu 19.10 a month ago without any additional modifications.

For all these days I had no issues with my wifi connection which itself is through an old Asus router that works in 2.4ghz band. However, since almost a week, I'm experiencing very unstable/slow connectivity. I also have a mobile hotspot which works in 5ghz with 3mbps speed and connecting my machine to this hotspot results in no connectivity issue that I'm experiencing with my home router.

I've tried several solutions, including enabling only 11n connectivity along with WPA2 security in router settings but that doesn;t seem to roll back the connectivity I used to have when I frist installed Ubuntu. I do not know if it's a fault wifi driver, since in software updates, it says 'This device is not working" for my Intel Wirless 8265/8275 chip (snapshot below). These are some of the stats:

```
sudo lshw -class network

*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 78
       serial: 90:78:41:fe:42:64
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-23-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:130 memory:ef000000-ef001fff


rfkill list

0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I also have this snapshot for extra info:

[image: screen1]

Comment: If it used to work before and it doesn't any more, it's probably because one of your neighbours has installed a very powerful new WiFi that pushes your WiFi away.  Change the channel on the router instead. (which makes this off-topic for Ask Ubuntu, unfortunately)

Comment: @Fabby Yes it seemed to be a channel problem. I've neabled a virtual access point separately for my linux machine and changed the channel. Wifi seems normal now.

Comment: Posting off-topic answer for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it used to work before and it doesn't any more, ask yourself:

*What changed?*

As in your case it's "Nothing" then maybe one of your neighbours has installed a very powerful new WiFi that pushes your WiFi away.

Therefore, change the channel on your router instead of trying to fix it on the Ubuntu side...

#### 0:-)

Comment: I was previously DK Bose :D

Comment: Merry Christman & a Happy New Year! I'm wondering if you're planning to stay on Manjaro KDE and, if so, if you'd share, perhaps in a chatroom, what you like and dislike about it. I use Kubuntu.

Comment: Posting late; but the channel thing worked.